# How to configure MariaDB in Django on Fedora 37

Tags: mysql, django, mariadb, fedora

I am creating a new Django project and would like to use mariadb instead of sqlite.
I have checked few guides (like this one: https://medium.com/code-zen/django-mariadb-85cc9daeeef8) as well as Django documentation. And from what I understand I need to have both mysql and mariadb installed to make it work.
I have installed mysqlclient in my virtual environment using pip3.
Then, I started my django project and edited and saved the DATABASES section of settings.py as advised in the above guide (I chose my own project name, username and password):

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databasesDATABASES = {
    ‘default’: {
    ‘ENGINE’: ‘django.db.backends.mysql’,
    ‘NAME’: ‘myproject’,
    ‘USER’:’yourusername’,
    ‘PASSWORD’:’yourpassword',
    ‘HOST’:’localhost’,
    ‘PORT’:’’,
    }
}
```

This is where the issue starts. I followed the guide and tried to install mariadb then:
`sudo dnf install mariadb`
But I got an error:

```
Error: 
 Problem: problem with installed package community-mysql-8.0.32-1.fc37.x86_64
  - package community-mysql-8.0.32-1.fc37.x86_64 conflicts with mariadb provided by mariadb-3:10.5.16-3.fc37.x86_64
  - package mariadb-3:10.5.16-3.fc37.x86_64 conflicts with community-mysql provided by community-mysql-8.0.32-1.fc37.x86_64
  - package community-mysql-8.0.30-2.fc37.x86_64 conflicts with mariadb provided by mariadb-3:10.5.16-3.fc37.x86_64
  - package mariadb-3:10.5.16-3.fc37.x86_64 conflicts with community-mysql provided by community-mysql-8.0.30-2.fc37.x86_64
  - conflicting requests
  - package community-mysql-8.0.32-1.fc37.x86_64 conflicts with mariadb provided by mariadb-3:10.5.18-1.fc37.x86_64
  - package mariadb-3:10.5.18-1.fc37.x86_64 conflicts with community-mysql provided by community-mysql-8.0.32-1.fc37.x86_64
  - package community-mysql-8.0.30-2.fc37.x86_64 conflicts with mariadb provided by mariadb-3:10.5.18-1.fc37.x86_64
  - package mariadb-3:10.5.18-1.fc37.x86_64 conflicts with community-mysql provided by community-mysql-8.0.30-2.fc37.x86_64
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

I did some research and it looks like in Fedora mysql and mariadb exclude each other. I wasn't able to find a solution to this problem.
Firstly, is this a correct way of adding mariadb in place of sqlite to Django project?
If so, how do I solve this exclusion problem of Fedora?

Comment: Do you need the `community-mysql` installed? If not use `dnf purge` to remove it.

Comment: I was being an idiot and assumed that community-mysql is a dependency of mysqlclient. I have just run ```sudo dnf install mariadb --allowerasing``` which completed successfully and was able to add mariadb to my new Django project. Thank you! Sometimes we need someone to point out the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

1. MariaDB is basically the same as MySQL, but with a more permissive license. Installing both at the same time is known to cause conflicts, so is often discouraged, unless you know your way around Unix like the back of your hand.
2. Your Django settings seems fine.
3. Check to see if SELinux is causing you issues. One way to check quickly is to turn it to permissive mode by doing `sudo setenforce 0` and checking your Django project is working fine or not (and later `sudo setenforce 1` to turn it back on i.e., enforcing mode)
4. You might also need `python3-devel` & `mariadb-devel`
5. Have you tried `sudo dnf install mariadb mariadb-server` then `sudo systemctl start mariadb` & then `sudo systemctl enable mariadb`